# Multiple and dynamic databases in doctrine 2

Tags: php, sql, database, doctrine-orm

I checked already multiple answers on stackoverflow but couldnt find a sufficient answer for that problem.

Imagine I have a MAIN database and multiple SLAVE databases. Based on some information in the MAIN database I will then know which SLAVE database I will connect to and which table I will use for my model.

**As an example:**

A Person entity can be connected to a database1234 database using the table person_india or to database7834 using a table person_uk etc. Which one I will connect to is decide on runtime and cant be configured before.

**What I found so far:**

I can directly bind a model to a database.table via

```
@Entity @Table(name="databaseName.tablename")
```

So Im able to join over databases. So basically Im ignoring the dbname in the connection params for the entityManager.

**Question:**

- How to dynamically set the information(database,table) for an entity on the fly?
- Will this affect caching?
- If this is not possible in a good manner. Is there any other orm which will provide me that kind of functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If something is unclear then please leave a comment.